# How QProcess internally works internally in linux?

Tags: linux, qt

How QProcess internally works in linux?

Comment: I think it starts a basic event loop when run.

Comment: @Paulo: IIRC, `QProcess` is the class you use for spawning child processes.  So it most likely uses `fork`/`exec`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: indeed, I was thinking of QApplication

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An oddly vague question.  I can only answer with "Use the source Luke, use the source":

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/corelib/io/qprocess_unix.cpp